# WifiSpecifier does not connect to Wifi

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, wifi

I want to connect the device to specific wifi.
So I write the code like this, but it doesn't

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    private lateinit var wifiNetworkSpecifier: WifiNetworkSpecifier

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

        //wifiNetworkSpecifier
        wifiNetworkSpecifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid("test1234")
            .setWpa2Passphrase("12345678")
            .build()

        //NetworkCallback
        networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                }else {

                }
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(null)
                connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
            }
        }

        //NetworkRequest
        val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
            .build()

        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)

    }
}
```

Is it right to use a wifi specifier to connect to a specific wifi?
No matter how hard I try, it's not connected
For reference, the ssid and password of the wifi are accurate.

Comment: Does it gives any error or warning?

Comment: @Nitish Yeah, but I solved my problem. when I removeCapability NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it shows the dialog which connect to specific wifi. Thanks you for answer